# Not able to locate the specific element on a specific website

Tags: html, selenium, automation

I'm trying to automate a website and I'm not able to locate the element on the following website. Can you guys please help me here?

- Go to the website https://flights-ca.gotogate.com/flights
- Go to the Source location and enter any city, e.g; Thunder Bay Now it will show you an option in the drop-down.

I want to select the option Thunder Bay, Canada, Ontario

I'm not able to locate the element and hence not able to find the xPAth.

Help is highly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: This is textbox aswell. Try Sendkeys directly. See if it accepts

Comment: I did SendKeys, but I want to select options from drop-down after the send keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Key here is how to inspect element appearing to select, after typing in textBox. You need to inspect it in **Debugger pause mode**. See below steps:

1. Go to page open developer inspection mode
2. Go to source Tab
3. Type in text box. it will show the matching options.
4. Now press F8, it will pause screen in debugger mode.
5. Now inspect the option you want to select.

In you case you can follow below steps to select dropdown:

```
fromCity = 'Thunder Bay'
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='thunder b']").send_keys(fromCity)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[div[contains(text(),'"+fromCity+"')]]").click()
```

**Note :** As you have not mentioned which scripting language you are using for your code. I have provided solution in python. Let me know if you are facing any issue in while converting to your scripting language.

Comment: //*[@class='Select-input']/input Just use this for xpath.